# select a particular tuple in angular

Tags: html, angular

in my angular application i have a list of schedule objects in schedule array that are displayed using ngFor.

i want that whenever i click the checkbox on the left of my schedule box that particular schedule is selected as current schedule and rest is set to false .

i also want that my default selected schedule  is the  one that is most recently added to the array.

here is my HTML code

```
<div class="Box" *ngFor="let schedule of availableSchedules">
            <div class="row width100">
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="round">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                    <label for="checkbox"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-11">
              <div class="row width100" style="font-size: larger;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  From : <span>{{schedule.startTime}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  To : <span>{{schedule.endTime}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
              <label for="days" style="font-size: larger;">Days</label>
              <div class="row" name="days" style="margin-top: 5px;padding-left: 5px;">
                <span class="chip" *ngFor="let day of schedule.days">{{day}}</span>
              </div>  
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

here is my ts code

```
currentSchedule = new tutorAvailablitySchedule();
availableSchedules: tutorAvailablitySchedule[] = [];

selectSchedule(schedule:tutorAvailablitySchedule) {
    this.currentSchedule = schedule;
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: stackblitz or codepen example would be easier to debug

Comment: @MrKhan suppose there are 10 objects in a string array and are displayed using ngFor. i want that whenever i click on that string or a checkbox.that particular string is selected as a currentString which is a new variable.

Comment: on select box and checkbox selection you  can to update the currentSchedule variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you should do the job:

```
<input type="checkbox"
  [ngModel]="schedule===currentSchedule"
  (ngModelChange)="selectSchedule($event ? schedule : null)" />
```

If you need to prevent an empty selection, you should use a radio button instead. In that case, you don't event need to define the `selectSchedule` function:

```
<input type="radio" name="schedule"
  [value]="schedule" 
  [(ngModel)]="currentSchedule"/>
```